# MainWP Plugin doesn't save advanced custom fields values

Tags: wordpress

Has anyone used the [MainWP Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/mainwp/) for managing multiple WordPress sites? 
I have recently been using it and on each site where I am using Advanced custom fields plugin for creating custom fields in my posts. But when I created the bulkpost using the MaiWP dashboard, the custom fields are not being saved when publishing new post. Has anyone ever encountered this problem and maybe resolved it?
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you facing any warning or error message when saving your posts ???
Have you tried by uninstalling plugin Wpmain, to make sure only culprit is plugin ... ??? kindly provide any further information for better understanding of your question and provide what you have tried so far ?

Comment: The fields created by advanced custom fields are not being saved at all. There is no error. The post saves as normal but after saving the custom fields are empty. The only data saved is the default posta data, which is excerpt, content, thumbnail. I tried reinstalling the plugin with no luck.